# What is the best way to indicate that a double value has not been initialized?

Tags: c++, null

I have a class CS which is to represent the co-ordinate system in 3D i.e.(x, y, z)

```
class CS
{
  private:
        double x;
        double y;
        double z;
}

CS::CS()
{
   x = NULL;//this causes x = 0//i want the address of x to be 0x000000 & not x = 0
   y = NULL;
   z = NULL:
}
```

I want that the user can create a CS (0, 0, 0).
In the constructor i want to initialise the address of x, y & z to NULL.
this is to differentiate between the user defined (0, 0, 0) & the default value.
I am creating the objects of CS dynamically, so there is **no** point in using the following code:

```
class CS
{
  private:
        double *x;
        double *y;
        double *z;
}

CS:CS()
{
    x = new double;
    x = NULL;
    //same for y & z
}
```

Primarily, i want to ***manually assign 0x000000 address*** to any variable(int or double or char) without using pointers.
any suggestions?

Comment: Have you considered just adding a flag `is_initialized`?  That would be the easy solution.

Comment: Why are they pointers in the first place, why not just doubles?

Comment: Are you looking for equivalent of nullable struct?

Comment: @JamesMcNellis could you show me some code...how will is_initialized know whether user has put the 0 value, or it is by default?

Comment: By the way, your second code sample really has "no point", as it constantly keeps creating memory leaks anyway. You should delve a little deeper into what variables and pointers really are and how they work. Then you will realize the invalidity and unanswerability of your question.

Comment: @CAD_coding: you'd need to add a flag to the structure to indicate whether it's initialised or not - there's no other way to tell. Alternatively, you could have a look at Boost.Optional, which gives you a nullable value type.

Comment: why don't let the default value be (0,0,0) ?

Comment: @CAD_coding: `difference between NULL & 0`:  In C++?  NULL is defined as `((void *)0)`.  So they're effectively the same thing.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Actually, `NULL` has to be defined as an integer literal without the cast to `void*` (or as `nullptr` in C++11). However, from the context, the question is asking about null *pointers* and zero-valued *objects*; the difference between these is huge.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: MSDN confirms what you say about NULL.  The conceptual difference between null pointers and zero-valued objects is huge, but the OP seemed to be wanting to store both in a `double`, and distinguish them.  Either way, it's the wrong approach.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can't change the positions of x,y,and z to be NULL, since there positions will *always* be offsets from the CS object.  They will always exist.  It's not that `CS` has an `x` like you have a car, it's like `CS` has an `x` like you have a head.  You can't *not* have a head.  If they were integers, you would have to make them pointers (like you said you didn't want to do), because that would be the only way to tell uninitialized from initialized.  However, `double`s have a magic value that is rarely used:

```
CS:CS()
: x(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN())
: y(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN())
: z(std::numeric_limits<double>::quiet_NaN())
{ }
```

Users probably won't be setting x, y, and z to (NOT A NUMBER) intentially.

Answer (score 4):

> Primarily, i want to manually assign 0x000000 address to any variable(int or double or char) without using pointers. any suggestions?

That's not what you want. What you *want* is the ability to detect whether a variable has been set or not.

Others have suggested things like using a specific floating-point value to detect the uninitialized state, but I suggest employing [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html). Consider:

```
class CS
{
  private:
    boost::optional<double> x;
    boost::optional<double> y;
    boost::optional<double> z;
}
```

`boost::optional` either stores the type you give to the template parameter or it stores nothing. You can test the difference with a simple boolean test:

```
if(x)
{
  //Has data
}
else
{
  //Has not been initialized
}
```

The downside is that accessing the data is a bit more complex:

```
x = 5.0; //Initialize the value. x now has data.
y = 4.0 * x; //Fails. x is not a double; it is an optional<double>.
y = 4.0 * (*x); //Compiles, but only works at runtime if x has a value.
```

Comment: hey, thanks a lot.
but i also want to know how to manually assign address to my variables
is it possible?

Comment: @CAD_coding: No. Variables do not even have to _have_ an address, if the compiler doesn't want them to.

Answer (score 2):

You have several options:

1. Use pointers.
2. Use a boolean flag alongside each variable indicating whether the variable has been set.
3. If the range of allowable values is limited, you could use a special value to stand for "not set". For `double`, a not-a-number is often a natural candidate. For `int` and `char` it's often more tricky to pick a good value.

None of these options is indisputably better than the other two as they involve different tradeoffs. Take your pick.

Answer (score 2):

You can't really represent it in the same number of bits without having a sentinel.  If 0 is a valid number, then you can't use it.  If you try and foist null handling into a value type you will have fundamentally incorrect and unmaintainable code.

When handling nulls properly you would expect to see an interface like this:

```
struct foo {
  virtual ~foo() {}
  virtual bool getX(double &val) = 0;
  virtual bool getY(double &val) = 0;
  virtual bool getZ(double &val) = 0;
};
```

The implementation can have a flag that it checks before access.

```
void some_func(foo *f) {
  double x, y, z;
  if (f->getX(x) && f->getY(y) && f->getZ(z)) {
    cout << x << ", " << y << ", " << z << endl;
  } else {
    throw std::logic_error("expected some values here");
  }
}
```

You don't want to use an invalid value and not know it.  Having to check the return values is tedious obviously, but it gives you the most control.  You could also have helpers or overloads that would throw if they weren't valid.

```
struct bar {
  double getX() {
    if (!valid)
      throw std::logic_error("bar is not valid");
    return x;
  }
  bool valid;
  double x, y, z; 
}
```

For me, the difference between `foo` and `bar` is that low level code handling the data shouldn't enforce a policy of whether the data is there or not.  At higher levels of abstraction you can and should have expectations of whether the data should valid when you go to use it.  The both can exist in a system, but `foo` is necessary.

Comment: I can't see how this solves his problem.  He wants to allocate an array of `CS[NUM]`, and tell which have had their data set.  How does your `foo` help?

Comment: @MooingDuck Unguarded value access when you want to express the concept of null is simply wrong.  The ceiling for that behavior is that every single developer on the project guards your invariants with crude discipline.  What good is a strategy that *at best* gives you a maintenance nightmare?

Comment: Or the value access could be guarded with an `assert`, which would be totally fine by me.  I just reread your interface and realized I misunderstood it at first.  I dislike requiring others to check a return value, but that's not worth the -1.  Could you put up a sample usage to clarify the usage of the interface, so I can remove the -1?[

Comment: @MooingDuck Updated.  Whether throw or assert, doesn't matter as long as its fail fast.  I've seen several organizations fail on null handling.  Most of the time they don't even understand what a gruesome time sink they've invested in.

Answer (score 2):

Why can't you simply do this:

```
class CS
{
public:
    // Constructs a CS initialized to 0, 0, 0
    CS() : x(0), y(0), z(0), is_initialized(false) {}

    // User defined values
    CS(double newX, double newY, double newZ) : x(newX), y(newY), z(newZ), is_initialized(true) {}

private:
    double x;
    double y;
    double z;

    // If you need to know that this was initialized a certain way, you could use this suggestion from the comments:
    bool is_initialized;
}
```

Comment: thank you... i was avoiding using extra variable in class to reduce memory usage

Answer (score 2):

One way to get the semantics of what you want would be to have the datatype of the coordinates be a type that carries with it a value indicating whether it has been assigned.  Something like this.

```
template<typename T>
class CoordinateValue {
   public:
       CoordinateValue() : uninitialized(true), val(0) {}
       CoordinateValue(T x) : uninitialized(false), val(x) {}
       void setVal(T x) {val = x; uninitialized= false}
       // Trivial getters
    private:
       T val;
       bool uninitialized;
};
```

I'd prefer something like this over cuter methods unless memory is really scarce for some reason.

If the coordinates are either all default or all set, then you can have a single flag rather than a coordinate datatype that includes the flag.

Comment: I'd say that this is as correct an answer as you can get for this question.  In a previous job, the class we had to do this was a template called `Nark<T>`. It lets you inspect to see if it has been assigned to.  The special case of a `Nark<bool>` is also known as a tri-boolean.

Comment: I would definitely recommend this approach if the "cuter" methods won't work for whatever it is that the OP wants to distinguish default values for.  (Also, I wouldn't use `default` as a variable name)

Comment: @Mooing: To be exact, you *can't* use `default` as a variable name, because it's a keyword for `switch` statements.

Comment: Thanks -- I'll change the name. That'll teach me to post code that I haven't run through the compiler.

Comment: Also made it a template per Michael Price's note.

Comment: @JohnMcG: Did you run that one through a compiler?  Is `boolean` an actual type?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you want to be able to tell the difference between an invalid, default constructed CS and a valid one with values `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)`. This is exactly what `boost::optional` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html is for.

Comment: @CAD_coding: Only MarkB understood?  Isn't NicolBolas's answer the same suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

> I want that the user can create a CS (0, 0, 0). In the constructor i
>   want to initialise the address of x, y & z to NULL. this is to
>   differentiate between the user defined (0, 0, 0) & the default value.
>   I am creating the objects of CS dynamically, so there is no point in
>   using the following code:

This is the problem. Firstly, default value? What default value? Why should there be a default value? That's wrong. And secondly, it's fundamentally impossible for you to change the address of any variable.

What you want cannot be done and even if it could, it would be a horrendously bad idea.

Comment: the default value is assigned in the constructur... i cannot let my variables have any garbage value!!!

Comment: @CAD_coding: Then set them to NULL in the constructor. You haven't explained why you need to differentiate between actual NULL and some other kind of NULL.

Comment: @CAD_coding: then set them to a good value, or make the default constructor illegal.

Comment: @CAD_coding: You completely can let variables have garbage values. It's your user's job to give you something meaningful to set them to.

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the address of a variable. And you can't assign pointer values (like `NULL`, or `nullptr` in C++) to a variable of a non-pointer type, such as `double`.

Comment: At least not without some icky casting.