# C++ Pass over uninitialized variable

Tags: c++, runtime, initialization

I need to ignore an uninitialized variable in C++ when I reach the end of my grid.

```
         pointMapIt++;
         float nextPointRow;
         if (pointMapIt != grid.points.end())
         {
             nextPointRow = 3.0;
             pointMapIt--;
         }

         if (point.dr != nextPointRow)
             //Do stuff
```

pointMapIt is an iterator passing through my grid points. It checks against nextPointRow every iteration. The program will crash at the final iteration, because nextPointRow will not have been set.

I cannot set nextPointRow to `0.0`, because `0.0` is an actual valid input. In fact, I really have no way of telling what nextPointRow will be. So what I really need is to be able to (initialize nextPointRow to and) check nextPointRow against NULL, like so:

```
         if (nextPointRow != null && point.dr != nextPointRow)
```

Is there a way I can do this or circumvent the issue altogether?

Comment: Move the second if into the first if? Or add an else to break the loop to the first if?

Comment: There is no such thing as a null `float` value.  You could maybe use an infinite or NaN value as a sentinel.  But it's probably more legible to just add a `bool` to track whether `nextPointRow` has been determined.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the best way to indicate that a double value has not been initialized?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7893531/what-is-the-best-way-to-indicate-that-a-double-value-has-not-been-initialized)

Comment: `null` isn't a thing. A primitive C++ data type has no notion of "not being set".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest might be setting `nextPointRow` to [`NAN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NaN).

Alternatively, have a boolean flag alongside `nextPointRow` that would indicate whether the latter contains a valid value.

Yet another option is to rearrange your code like so:

```
     pointMapIt++;
     if (pointMapIt != grid.points.end())
     {
         float nextPointRow = 3.0;
         pointMapIt--;
         if (point.dr != nextPointRow) {
             //Do stuff
```

Comment: For the initial proposal, code would be: `float nextPointRow = std::numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();`

Answer (score 3):

You should use something like Boost.Optional for this:

```
boost::optional<float> nextPointRow;  // initially unset

if (condition) { nextPointRow = 3.0; }
else           { ++pointMapIt;       }

if (nextPointRow && nextPointRow != point.dr) { /* stuff */ }
```

Additionally, you should avoid the unnecessary back-and-forth for the iterator by using an `else` clause.